# Convert NSData to NSString and ignore null bytes?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, foundation

I need to convert a NSData object to an NSString. It is meant to be gibberish but I need it for debbuging.

When I use NSString's initWithData, it breaks as the data has NULL bytes. How can I make it ignore the null bytes and get a proper string?

Comment: Need a little more information. NSString has -initWithData:encoding: (not -initWithData:). What encoding are you using? Showing your code could be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to convert data that is not text into a string? And what string encoding do you want to pretend it is? It really sounds like you're going about this the wrong way, but it's hard to tell what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the NSData to a NSMutableData, byte by byte, skipping any null bytes. Then initialise the string from that.